# How can I cache the mathobjects like clans and couplets in memory?

Tags: algebraixlib

Is it possible to cache the mathobjects using algebraixlib? I would like to store mathobjects like clans and couplets in memory and use it whenever I need it.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a `MathObject`, it is stored in memory. As long as you have a reference to it, it will remain in memory during the runtime of your program. Depending on your needs, there are several ways to cache the `MathObject`s of interest. One way would be to store them in a dictionary.

If you want to store them *between* program runs, you need to store them on disk. `algebraixlib` provides the module `algebraixlib.io.mojson` for (de-)serializing `MathObject`s. You can use this module to serialize clans and couplets to disk, and at program startup read them from disk. However, you need to manage the objects and their associated files yourself; there is no 'automatic' cache.

Comment: I think I will explain more to make it clear. I am loading various CSV files as clans using algebraixlib. I use these clans every time in order to create a tuple. I do these every time when I create one row or a tuple. I would like to store these clans in memory so I do not have to load them in memory every time when I create a tuple. Please let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: @van: Can you provide a minimal code sample to clarify your problem? When you load a CSV file as clan, the resulting clan is stored in memory and available as long as you have a reference to it.

Comment: @ Gerhard I can not explain my question here since I don't have much characters left. Hoe can I reach you to explain my question ?

Comment: @van: You can edit your question and add more specifics. This should give you enough room.